# Cannot install .deb pakages using software centre ubuntu 17.04

Tags: bug-reporting

Today after installing ubuntu I encountered a problem when I was trying to install chrome  I first downloded the file then when I clicked software centre got opened I clicked install button many times but it didn t get installed

Answer (score 1):

Use `gdebi` to install .deb files, instead of `Software Center`, as it's a lot more reliable, and more user-friendly.

In `terminal`...

```
sudo apt-get update # to update the software databases
sudo apt-get install gdebi # to install gdebi, if it's not already there
```

Find the Chrome .deb file that you downloaded. Right-click on it, and choose Properties, and change the "open with" default from `Software Center` to `gdebi`.

Then double-click on the .deb file to install Chrome.

Comment: There is no need to install `gdebi` just to install Chrome. The same effort will install Chrome already.

Comment: @Pilot6 I've seen systems that didn't have `gdebi`.

Comment: Ubuntu does not have `gdebi`. I mean that you don't need it to install Chrome.

Comment: @Pilot6  Would you use `dpkg`? Yes, but double-clicking the .deb file won't get you there. Much easier for the user.

Comment: thanks a lot it worked i think ubuntu should improve their software centre

Answer (score 0):

Why not try using the terminal way

```
dpkg -i <packge name>.deb
```

if not successful you might get errors why.

Comment: I tried to install gdebi by  software centre

Comment: But there is no gdebi spftware centre

Comment: i have installed google chrome sucessfully by gdebi