# 17.10 latest Ubuntu Version Install Unsupported Files

Tags: 17.10, google-chrome, files, google, opera

I am currently very frustrated with 17.10; I am unable to install Opera browser or google chrome because unsupported ... via Ubuntu Software or Terminal using apt-get install DEB file such as "/Downloads/opera-stable_48.0.2685.50_amd64" ... any other suggestions? It was not this complicated in 17.04 or before versions. If this continues, I might go back to just using windows.

-No message on Ubuntu Software ... It does not allow "Install" even after authentication with my password.
-On Terminal states unsupported: "E: Unsupported file /Downloads/opera-stable_48.0.2685.50_amd64 given on commandline"

And yes, downloaded the DEB files of opera and google chrome ... in my download folder and extracted to unlock.

Fixed ... closed. 
It needed: sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras

Now functioning normal. Thank you all for the help and suggestions. Please note I am new to this Operating system and learning ... don't take my questions the wrong way. All the best.

Comment: what is DPK??  you need to use chromium or download the deb package for the browser you want to use.

Comment: Please edit your question and include the details about the errors you are getting.

Answer (score 2):

A few broad issues:

First, this is a long standing issue with software center :

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-software/+bug/1672424

If you search this site you will see it has been long standing

[Cannot install .deb pakages using software centre ubuntu 17.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/929339/cannot-install-deb-pakages-using-software-centre-ubuntu-17-04)

[Problem with .deb packages on Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760638/problem-with-deb-packages-on-ubuntu-16-04)

Just pointing out that your claim " It was not this complicated in 17.04 or before versions." is not the case. The issue with software center has been since 16.04 and the installation of chrome / opera on 17.10 is the same as it was on 17.04 .

Furthermore threatening to go to windows or OSX or another version of Linux or any other OS does not really motivate people to help you as that may in fact be the best choice for you.

Additionally, that is not how to install software anyways.

See : [How do I install applications in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/307280/how-do-i-install-applications-in-ubuntu)

Use chromium, it is in the repositories, and is the same as chrome, just without the branding.

Or use the chrome repository, same as 17.04 : [How to install Google Chrome](https://askubuntu.com/questions/510056/how-to-install-google-chrome)

For opera, same as 17.04  : [How can I install the Opera browser from the terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/765483/how-can-i-install-the-opera-browser-from-the-terminal)

And Finally, neither chrome or opera are in the Ubuntu repositories so you need to express your frustration with their linux support (or lack of it) directly to them, not Ubuntu. Your anger / frustration is misdirected.

Your "problem" is for the most part self inflicted by insisting on using applications not supported by Ubuntu (try installing unsupported apps on Windows and you will find similar results) . There are many web browsers in the ubuntu  repositories to choose from and I have a hard time believing that none meet your needs.

That decision is compounded by your failure to follow instructions for installing software in general and these 2 apps (chrome and opera) specifically have repositories you should be aware of since you used 17.04, should be using rather than downloading .deb and installing with software center.